# IE Driver download location Link for Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Usually I download the drivers for Selenium from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

but I couldn't find the IEDriver Server at this location now. Can any one please share the latest download location?

Answer (score 12):

The downloads have moved, it says that on that very page:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Great link but if you click it in IE11, you cant use the back button to get back to this Stack question.

Comment: Agreed. This is already a 4 year old answer, so will already be out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below link to download IE Driver latest version

[IE Driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: The latest one is 2.42.0

Answer (score 2):

You can download IE Driver (both 32 and 64-bit) from Selenium official site: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

[32 bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0.zip)

[64 bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0.zip)

IE Driver is also available in the following site:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html